# webhost (azure) blocks ajax calls

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, azure

I have a [.php script](http://coobs.azurewebsites.net/scripts/twitterproxy2.php) on my azure server which returns JSON. When you visit the link in your browser, it shows you the JSON.

I want to make an ajax call to this script, but none of my ajax calls to the server get through. I have no idea why.

[webpage that executes a failed ajax call to the .php script](http://coobs.azurewebsites.net/scripts/ajaxcall.html)

Could it have something to do with cross-domain ajax calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution here: [origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) ...

It's the browser who is blocking cross-origin ajax calls. You can overcome this by allowing your script to receive ajax calls from every domain by adding this to your script header:

C#:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

php:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```